# Companion matrices over the Galois field with two elements

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, matrix-decomposition, companion-matrices

Let us denote $\mathbb{F}_2$ by the Galois field with two elements. The companion matrix of the monic polynomial $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$ is the square matrix defined as $$C(f)=\begin{pmatrix}
 0& & &-a_0 \\
 1& & &-a_1\\
 &\ddots& &\vdots\\
 0& &1&-a_{n-1} 
\end{pmatrix}.$$ I am considering about the companion matrix $A$ of $x^n+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$. I wonder if there exists a matrix $B$ such that $A=B^2$. I tried it but got no results. If not, can it express into commutators of involutions? I know for sure that it is a product of two involutions.

Comment: *"I wonder if there exists a matrix  such that $A=B^2$. I tried it but got no results"* How much trying did you do?  E.g. your companion matrix is the cyclic shift operator and has order n.  Consider $n=2$. Now $\big \vert GL_2(\mathbb F_2)\big \vert = 6$, so the existence of a $B$ (i.e. an order $4$ element) would violate Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: If $n$ is odd, try $B=A^{(n+1)/2}$.

Comment: Oh, I got it. However, what if n is even greater than $2$? @JyrkiLahtonen